# Center span in a table cell

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center the captive below the image in the table. I can fix it on the bottom of the cell or center it horizontally but not both actions simultaneously.Is it because of the relative/absolute position?

```html
<body>
<style>
#sum td{
 position:relative;
 text-align:center !important;
 vertical-align: center;
 width:400px;
 }
#sum tr{
 height:280px;
 }
#sum td span{
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0;
 display:block;
 text-align:right;
 }
</style>

<content>
 <div>
  <ul>
   <table id="sum"> 
    <tr>
     <td class="col-md-4">
      <li><img class="pic"src="#">
      <span>xxx
      </span>
      </li>
     </td>
    </tr> 
   </table>
  </ul>
 </div>
</content>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to center the text underneath the image, no need for absolute positioning. Also, you have a random `ul` and `li` elements mixed in with the table, and the way you're using it is invalid.

```html
<head>
  <style>
    #sum td{
     position:relative;
     text-align:center !important;
     vertical-align: center;
     width:400px;
     }
    #sum tr{
     height:280px;
     }
    #sum td span{
     display:block;
     text-align:center;
     }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <content>
    <div>
      <table id="sum">
        <tr>
          <td class="col-md-4">
            <img class="pic" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1980294624/DJT_Headshot_V2_400x400.jpg">
            <span>xxx</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </content>
</body>
```

If you want to use absolute positioning, it will position the text over the image, not underneath it. To make the text span the entire width of it's parent, you need to add `position: relative;` to the parent, then either `width: 100%;` or `left: 0; right: 0;` to the span.

```html
<head>
  <style>
    #sum td{
     position:relative;
     text-align:center !important;
     vertical-align: center;
     width:400px;
     }
    #sum tr{
     height:280px;
     }
    #sum td {
      position: relative;
    }
    #sum td span{
     text-align:center;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0; right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
     }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <content>
    <div>
      <table id="sum">
        <tr>
          <td class="col-md-4">
            <img class="pic" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1980294624/DJT_Headshot_V2_400x400.jpg">
            <span>xxx</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </content>
</body>
```

Comment: The probem is that I have images of different sizes and I have to include the  line about bottom position another way the text isn't aligned vertically.

Comment: @AnnaŠtulcová I don't understand. Be sure to specify the problem(s) clearly in your OP so we don't waste one another's time. You didn't mention other images, why you have to use bottom positioning, or anything about vertical alignment in your OP.